# Format decimal in float

Tags: c++, winapi

Both of my operands in `TCHAR` type and I convert them to `double` because my operands can be integers or double. When I do `1.5 + 1` I've got `2.500000`. But I want `2.5`. I know how to solve a problem using `printf`, but I need to use my result `MessageBox`. How can I solve it?

```
double result = _wtof(firstOperand) + _wtof(secondOperand);
wstring ans = to_wstring(result);
MessageBox(NULL, ans.c_str(), L"Result", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_string` (and `to_wstring`) do not allow you to control precision (and your output is a precision problem).

To control precision, you should use either `snprintf` or `std::ostringstream` to first prepare the string, and than display it with `MessageBox`.

Comment: If your operands are TCHAR, then you probably want `_sntprintf_s` so that your code can compile for either ANSI or wide mode.  The `t` is for `TCHAR`.  The `_s` suffix stands for "safe," which means the function takes the size of the buffer as a parameter in order to offload some of the overflow checking from the caller.  (It's not perfectly safe, but it's safer.)  It's possible but harder to make the stream solution flexible enough to handle `TCHAR`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::wostringstream ToMsgBox;
ToMsgBox << result;
std::wstring ans = ToMsgBox.str();
```

Or quick and dirty:

```
std::wstring ans = to_wstring(result);
ans.resize(test.find_first_of('.') + 2);
```